# cache javascript file in all pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, caching

I have a question about caching. Consider we have jQuery library in Page1 and has another link to jQuery lib to Page2.

Does page2 use cached version of jQuery in we first request for Page1 then Page2?

Does it depends on Browser? or coding style?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the url of the jquery library stays the same then all of the modern browsers will cache that file if it's on default settings, so on the second and all subsequent requests until it's expired it will be retrieved from Cache.

That is 1 of the reasons to use a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network), so that if the user perhaps visited a site that used the same CDN to the javascript file it will be retrieved from cache.

**EDIT**

As Daniel Kurka mentioned, the response header can state that the file should not be cached, but this should almost never be the case with a jquery file...

Comment: can we create CDN using a server? for creating CDN what we need?

Comment: You would normally use an existing CDN like google or microsoft or somebody big that will be used alot. Jquery also has their own cdn, just google jquery CDN

Comment: you are right that headers will be set right if you use a CDN (thats the point of a CDN anyway)

Comment: these `Response Headers` belong to user browser settings? or my web site?

Comment: It is the http response from the server where you are retrieving the javascript file from, which I guess at this stage would be your server if you are not using a cdn at the moment. You can use fiddler(www.fiddler2.com) to see if a file is being cached or not

Answer (score 0):

Yes that file will be cached, except that you've added it to page2 with another url.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the http headers of your server when serving the javascript file, as well as the  settings of the clients browser.

For a basic explanation you can take a look at: http://www.web-caching.com/mnot_tutorial/how.html

So there is no simple yes or no, if you want the file to be cached you need to validate that you are setting proper headers in your GET responses.